# SIAM bibtex style with author year

Tags: bibtex, natbib, abbrvnat.bst

I am trying to produce a bibliography style like this:

[image]

For more info check [SIAM Style Manual](https://www.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/Journals/stylemanual/SIAM_STYLE_GUIDE_2019.pdf), section 15.1 on page 88).

The journal's default `bst` file (download [link](https://www.siam.org/Portals/0/Macros/Online/siamonline_190516.zip)) only produces numbered style, but they accept author-year style above as well. The closest I can get is with `abbrvnat` style,

```
% In preamble
\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}

% In document
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{References}
```

But the authors are not `textsc`. Also I like to remove urls and dois from the references. How should I configure the style? Thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few, major differences between your preferred formatting style for entries of type `@article` and what's produced by the `abbrvnat` bibliography style. E.g, the `abbrvnat` style places the year at the very end of the entry, not after the authors in parentheses; it encases the title field in double quotes instead of rendering it in italics; and it italicizes the `journal` field instead of using the upright font shape. A bibliography style that *does* render the author names in small-caps is `ecta`; however, it also doesn't fully meet your formatting requirements.

Comment: (continued from the previous comment) Something that might endear the `ecta` (short for "Econometrica", by the way) to you is that it ignores `doi` and `url` fields. :-)